# How do I get a list of uploaded videos for a certain channel with the new YouTube Data API (V3)?

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to get a list of video ids for all uploaded videos to a channel.  I would also like to use the new version of the YouTube Data API (V3).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have to get the upload playlist id to get each videos uploaded.  To get that, you need to get the channel id.  After you have the playlist id from the channel id, it is pretty simple.  I have written out the steps for all three below.

Also, we offer [PubSubHubBub](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/10/pubsubhubbub-for-youtube-activities.html) which allows you to be alerted every time a new video is added to a channel, or you could use [SUP](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_sup) (V2) to see which resources have changed before making the calls.

**Instructions to get video ids for all uploaded videos for a channel in V3**

1. Get the channel id for the channel you want (you probably only need to do this once, then you can save it)

   - Use [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)
   - Set **type** to **channel**
   - Set **q** to the name of the channel you want
   - Grab the **channel id** (something like this: "channelId": "UC0X2VuXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
2. Get the playlist id for the channel uploads using the channel id from step 1  (you probably only need to do this once, then you can save it)

   - Use [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)
   - Set **id** to UC0X2VuXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX from step 1
   - Grab the **uploads** key from **contentDetails** (something like this: "uploads": "UU0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
3. Get the videos via the playlistitems in the playlist using the playlist id from step 2

   - Use [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)
   - Set **playlistId** to UU0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX from step 2
   - Go through each PlaylistItem and pull out the video id

Comment: I've found this API to be very chatty, you have to make at least three queries to get something meaningful.

Comment: You can't get the MP4 URL. You should use the iframe embed or Android Player APIs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: can somebody share the code regarding this, I am very new to this and i am not getting how to start.

Comment: Well, THAT'S an answer I can work with! Thank your very much, to bad I can not give more than one upvote! Love SO <3

Comment: Would it also fetch videos whose privacyStatus is 'private or hidden' ?

Comment: Get result: `items": []`, but it really has many videos on the web

Comment: This approach is not bringing all the video IDs in the channel. I pulled video details using YT Analytics API. That list have 100+ video IDs that did not show up in the list of video IDs I pulled using the approach suggested here (YT Data API). Does this 'upload playlist' will have all the videos in the channel? If not how can you pull all videos IDs?

Comment: The API will only return a maximum of 50 results per page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253925/youtube-data-api-v3-php-search-pagination

Comment: @codingjeremy, can you please get list of videos from this channel... I tried your answer , but it's not getting this channel videos list.   https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKwKHktBsfFI3YpS3ymDKWQ/featured

Comment: Try with api explorer first on the web. If you look at the links for each page above, there is a section where you can 'execute' the code on the web page and see results (before you try specific library):
You already got the channel id: UCKwKHktBsfFI3YpS3ymDKWQ. Next you get the playlist id from 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list, this gives you UUKwKHktBsfFI3YpS3ymDKWQ. Go to the last API page, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list, scroll down to the execute button. Put in that playlist id as UU...KWQ and you should get the list.

Answer (score 10):

In the meantime, there is a much easier way:

- Use the channels.list
- set forUsername = [CHANNELNAME]
- set part = contentDetails

`grab $data->items[0]->contentDetails->relatedPlaylists->uploads --> [PLAYLISTID]`

- Use playlistItems.list
- Set playlistId = [PLAYLISTID] from step 1
- Go through each PlaylistItem and pull out the video ids

Comment: Same comment as above... You can't get the MP4 URL. You should use the iframe embed or Android Player APIs: developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: This is the one solution !

Comment: Get result: `items": []`, but it really has many videos on the web

Comment: When channel name has multiple words (separated by spaces), this method won't work.