# How do I use Youtube Data API V3 to fetch channel uploads using chanel's username?

Tags: youtube-api

I've explored most of this topic using the previous question [How do I get a list of uploaded videos for a certain channel with the new YouTube Data API (V3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13504899/1402315), but I wanted some specifics that build upon the answer given.

Is it possible to use the channel's username without calling a search query to get the channel ID? I have an https request that can get a search list shown below, but I'd rather not waste API quotas when I know the exact channel username.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q={channel_username}&key={my_api_key}&part=snippet
```

My hack for this is just take a videoid from the channel and extract a uploader ID from there, but its not elegant and won't work if the upload is removed.

Also, once I've worked my way down to getting the uploads key, how can I get a json that shows all of the uploads and not just a list of 25? If I do have to recursively call pages of uploads, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think that to get a channel, using the channel's username, the only option is to use the search, and the best strategy to minimize the use of quota is to use a cache, or save the channel ID.

For a full list of videos uploaded, as JSON, you can use contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads (the ID of the playlist that contains the channel's uploaded videos) and retrieve the PlaylistItems, using pages with 50 items per page, and using the nextPageToken value to retrieve each  page in the result set.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer. The correct way to go about it is to query the site using the search, but directly state the type of list to respond with, in effect searching only channels. This is done by

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q={search_term}&key={API_key}&type=channel&part=snippet
```

As you can see the type is channel. By searching with a search term of the exact channel username, you'll get a return list with the first item object as the channel, and you can store the channel ID and upload ID from there.

Answer (score 0):

To update this answer, you need to recognise the "quota limits".
As such, to use the "**search?q=[search]**" will incur a 100 quota usage.
Better to use "**channels?part=id&forUsername={username]**" as is only a quota of 1.

Then you can use "**channels?part=id,snippet ....... &id={channel_ID]**" to grab all your data