# youtube data api v3 php search pagination?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i am trying with youtube api v3 php search...

first time i'm using this api for this i am beginner...

i have 3 question;

1) how can below search list showing pagination numbers? (per page 50 result)

2) how can video duration show in list? (3:20 min:second)

3) how can order viewCount

```
if ($_GET['q']) {
  require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
  require_once 'src/contrib/Google_YoutubeService.php';
  $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'my key';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);
  $youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

  try {
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => 50,
      'type' => "video",
    ));

  foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {

    $videos .= '<li style="clear:left"><img src="'.$searchResult['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'].'" style="float:left; margin-right:18px" alt="" /><span style="float:left">'.$searchResult['snippet']['title'].'<br />'.$searchResult['id']['videoId'].'<br />'.$searchResult['snippet']['publishedAt'].'<br />'.$item['contentDetails']['duration'].'</span></li>';
}




$htmlBody .= <<<END
    <ul>$videos</ul>
END;
  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
}
```

Comment: any solution you got? I am also facing same problem?

Comment: not find any solution and break :( if you are find share with me too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**1) how can below search list showing pagination numbers? (per page 50 result)**

You need to write your own cacheing logic to implement this feature because with every result you get two tokens "NextPageToken" and "PreviousPageToken" and subsequent query must contain that token number to get next page or previous page token like below.

So whenever results are not available at cache then you should send either nextpagetoken or previous page token.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=API_KEY&part=snippet&q=japan&maxResults=10&order=date&pageToken=NEXT_or_PREVIOUS_PAGE_TOKEN

In particular your case where you need 50 pages per page and you are showing 3 pagination like (1,2,NEXT) then you need to fetch results two times. Both the results you will keep in cache so for page 1 and 2 results will be retrieved from cache. For next you make it sure that you are making query google again by sending nextPageToken.

Thus to show pagination 1-n and every page 50 results then you need to make n-1 queries to google api. But if you are showing 10 results per page then you cane make single query of 50 results using which you can show first 5 pages (1-5) with the help of retrieved results and at next you should again send next page token like above.

NOTE- Google youtube api provide 50 results max.

**2) how can video duration show in list? (3:20 min:second)**

Youtube API v3 do not return video duration at simple first search response. To get video duration we need to make one extra call to youtube api like below.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID1%2CVIDEO_ID2&part=contentDetails&key=API_KEY    (max 50 IDs)

This issue is highlighted in "http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4294".I posted my answer here too.

Hence if we want to display video duration then we need to make two calls every time.

**3) how can order viewCount**

Trigger below query it will provide results ordered by view count.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=KEY&part=snippet&q=japan&maxResults=5&order=viewCount

For detail please refer this - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#order

Comment: possible example share?

Comment: please use your API token in above urls.

Comment: i use api, localhost search.php work when i put server. giving error.


`code`
Warning: require_once(contrib/Google_YoutubeService.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/youtube/y.php on line 26 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'contrib/Google_YoutubeService.php' (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/youtube/google-api-php-client/src:google-api-php-client/src') in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/youtube/y.php on line 26
`code`

Comment: I am also using API but i am not using google provided code. I am preparing above urls. You can register your IP with the API service and then trigger above url through any webbrowser. 
So you need to write a script which can trigger two url
1- to get regural results
2- to get snippet

Comment: i don't know i cant fix this. my english to not enough for explain. i added my website IP to api console

Answer (score 3):

The youTube API V3 is somehow complicated compare to API V2.

To the question above, my approach is not for search result rather is to retrieve user uploaded videos. I believe this can be useful

[References](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests)

The way you create pagination in v3 is not the  same as in v2 where you can make your call simply like

```
$youtube = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Qtube247/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=50";
```

In v3 you need to make two or three calls the first one will be to get the channel detail and second call will be to retrieve playlist from where we will get the channel playlist Id and finally retrieve individual video data.

I am using Php CURL

```
$youtube = “https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=yourChannelIdgoeshere&key=yourApiKey”;
```

Here we retrieve user playlist ID

```
$result = json_decode($return, true);
$playlistId=$result['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];
```

we define pagetoken

```
$pageToken=’’;
```

Each time user click control button we retrieve pagetoken from session[] and feed the curl url, and in turn will produce nextpagetoken or prevpagetoken. Whatever you feed the url the Api know what set of list to populate.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ptk']) && $_REQUEST['ptk’]!==''){
$pageToken=$_REQUEST['ptk’];

}
```

Here we retrieve user playlist

```
$ playlistItems =”https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&pageToken=”.$pageToken.”&maxResults=50&playlistId=$playlistId&key= yourApiKey”;
```

If user has more than maxResult, we should have nextPageToken, take for an example user has  200 uploaded videos,the first pagetoken may be **CDIQAA** and next pagetoken may be **CGQQAA** while previous may be **CDIQAQ** , something like that so is not a number.

Here we save the pagetoken

```
if(isset($result['nextPageToken'])) { $_SESSION[nextToken]=$result['nextPageToken'];
}

if(isset($result['prevPageToken'])) { $_SESSION[prevToken]=$result['prevPageToken'];
}
```

we can then create our control button <>

```
$next=$_SESSION[nextToken];

$prev=$_SESSION[prevToken];
```

The control button here

```
<a href=”?ptk=<?php echo $prev?>” ><<prev</a>

<a href=”?ptk=<?php echo $next?>” >next>></a>
```

From  here when user click link it set either next or prev page in session variable (go to up to see how this work)

To get video duration we use same Php curl

```
$videoDetails="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status&id=videoIdHere&key=yourApiKey";
```

$videoData = json_decode($return, true);

$duration =  $videoData['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration'];

$viewCount =  $videoData['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];

you may get something like this `('PT2H34M25S')`

I have answer a question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393230/convert-youtube-api-v3-video-duration-in-php/26463456#26463456) which show you how to convert the duration data

[See Working Demo Here](http://www.tubentertain.com/t/)