# Convert youtube Api v3 video duration in php

Tags: php, regex, youtube-api

how do i convert PT2H34M25S to 2:34:25

I searched and used this code. I'm new to regex can someone explain this ? and help me with my issue

```
function covtime($youtube_time){
        preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$youtube_time,$parts);
        $hours = floor($parts[0][0]/60);
        $minutes = $parts[0][0]%60;
        $seconds = $parts[0][1];
        if($hours != 0)
            return $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
        else
            return $minutes.':'.$seconds;
    }
```

but this code only give me HH:MM

so dumb found the solution :

```
   function covtime($youtube_time){
            preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$youtube_time,$parts);
            $hours = $parts[0][0];
            $minutes = $parts[0][1];
            $seconds = $parts[0][2];
            if($seconds != 0)
                return $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
            else
                return $hours.':'.$minutes;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not giving you MM:SS (the second case in your conditional)? I don't see a code path that could output HH:MM.

Comment: it is giving me MM:SS but not HH:MM:SS

Comment: And are you sure you tried it with a video over an hour long? Also, the input format example you give in your question clearly has 3 separate digit sequences, so why does your code only consider the first 2?

Comment: just found the solution have posted it above thanks for your help

Comment: @DanielEuchar, I edited my answer with a revised function for you to look at.  There is still more validation that can be done.  Also it looks like someone removed the edit you put into your question.

Comment: solution fails on videos that report a duration of 1:00:01. see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35836604

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Using DateTime class

You could use PHP's DateTime class to achieve this. This solution is much simpler, and will work even if the format of the quantities in the string are in different order. A regex solution will (most likely) break in such cases.

In PHP, `PT2H34M25S` is a valid date period string, and is understood by the DateTime parser. We then make use of this fact, and just add it to the Unix epoch using [`add()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/datetime.add.php) method. Then you can format the resulting date to obtain the required results:

```
function covtime($youtube_time){
    if($youtube_time) {
        $start = new DateTime('@0'); // Unix epoch
        $start->add(new DateInterval($youtube_time));
        $youtube_time = $start->format('H:i:s');
    }
    
    return $youtube_time;
}   

echo covtime('PT2H34M25S');
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/366854)

Comment: wow this is so much better but in my wamp server this gave me a error Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateInterval::__construct() [<a href='dateinterval.--construct'>dateinterval.--construct</a>]: Unknown or bad format ()

Comment: @DanielEuchar: Can you add `var_dump($youtube_time);` inside the function, and tell me what it outputs when you try it with your time string?

Comment: sometimes i get PT2H34M25S and sometimes PT3M22S depends on the video length

Comment: try to define if it has hours:minutes:seconds then use this function instead you can always do a switch case and in each of your cases you do: e.g `return $start->format('g:i:s'); //for hours:minutes:seconds`

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki: Yup, this can be improved in many ways. I leave it to the user to figure out how to modify the function with respect to their requirements :)

Comment: By the way use `return $start->format('H:i:s');` instead of `g` put a capital `H` this will convert the time perfectly even if u pass only minutes or seconds

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki: Not sure I understand. Could you give a sample input for which `H:i:s` would work but `g:i:s` won't?

Comment: `<?php
/**
 *  Return the youtube video duration
 * @param $youtube_time
 * @return time
 */
function covtime($youtube_time){
 $start = new DateTime('@0'); // Unix epoch
 $start->add(new DateInterval($youtube_time));
 return $start->format('H:i:s');
}

echo  covtime('PT34M25S');`

as you can see no hours passed

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki: Could you give a sample input for which H:i:s would work but g:i:s won't?

Comment: 'g:i:s' won't work perfectly if we pass youtube time without hours or minutes, just try it and you will see what i mean

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki: Wow, thanks. Don't know how I missed that until now. Thank you, I've now updated the answer to reflect this :)

Comment: Some styling for those extra zeros: ``if ( substr( $start, 0, 5 ) === '00:00' ) {
    $start = substr( $start, 4 );
  } else if ( substr( $start, 0, 3 ) === '00:' ) {
    $start = substr( $start, 3 );
  }
  return $start;```

Answer (score 12):

Both **Amal**'s and **Pferate**'s solutions are great!
However, **Amal** solution keep giving me 1Hr extra. Below is my solution which is same with **Amal**  but difference approach and this work for me.

```
$date = new DateTime('1970-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT2H34M25S'));
echo $date->format('H:i:s')
```

[`datetime->add()` reference](http://php.net//manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: It works. The Date part is not important. So maybe you could use $date = new DateTime('00:00');

Answer (score 6):

Here's my solution which handles missing H, M or S (test a [video with a reported length of 1:00:01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dFvc42g8CA) and you'll see the problem with other answers). Seconds alone are presented as 0:01, but if you want to change that just change the last else to `elseif($M>0)` and add an else for seconds e.g. `else { return ":$S" }`

```
// convert youtube v3 api duration e.g. PT1M3S to HH:MM:SS
// updated to handle videos days long e.g. P1DT1M3S
function covtime($yt){
    $yt=str_replace(['P','T'],'',$yt);
    foreach(['D','H','M','S'] as $a){
        $pos=strpos($yt,$a);
        if($pos!==false) ${$a}=substr($yt,0,$pos); else { ${$a}=0; continue; }
        $yt=substr($yt,$pos+1);
    }
    if($D>0){
        $M=str_pad($M,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $S=str_pad($S,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return ($H+(24*$D)).":$M:$S"; // add days to hours
    } elseif($H>0){
        $M=str_pad($M,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $S=str_pad($S,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return "$H:$M:$S";
    } else {
        $S=str_pad($S,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return "$M:$S";
    }
}
```

Comment: Best solution to the "YouTube API duration timestamp" conundrum. Tested and works in all cases.

Comment: this fails for video id: WBu2pJpgKEo.

`contentDetails.duration = P1DT3H8S`

from the [data api docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails): "If the video is at least one day long, the letters P and T are separated, and the value's format is **P#DT#H#M#S.**"

so, here's an amendment:
`$yt = str_replace('P', '', $yt);`
`$yt = str_replace('T', '', $yt);`

nice solution otherwise! edit: additionally, handling the `D` case is necessary, but trivial to implement with the current setup of the function.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at your `$parts` variable after it's created.

```
var_dump($parts);
```

Compare that output with how you are defining your variables.  It *should* stand out pretty obviously after that.

I guess my next question after that is what variations of the input time string are you expecting and what validation will you be doing?  The variations of the input format you want to handle will affect the complexity of the actual code written.

Edit:
Here is an updated function to handle missing numeric values (if the hours or minutes is omitted) and seconds/hours over 60 (not sure if this will ever happen).  This doesn't validate the label for the numbers:

- 1 number: assume it is seconds
- 2 numbers: assume it is minutes, seconds
- 3 or more numbers: assume first 3 numbers are hours, minutes, seconds (ignoring another numbers)

More validation can be added to look into validating the input string.

```
<?php
function covtime($youtube_time) {
    preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$youtube_time,$parts);

    // Put in zeros if we have less than 3 numbers.
    if (count($parts[0]) == 1) {
        array_unshift($parts[0], "0", "0");
    } elseif (count($parts[0]) == 2) {
        array_unshift($parts[0], "0");
    }

    $sec_init = $parts[0][2];
    $seconds = $sec_init%60;
    $seconds_overflow = floor($sec_init/60);

    $min_init = $parts[0][1] + $seconds_overflow;
    $minutes = ($min_init)%60;
    $minutes_overflow = floor(($min_init)/60);

    $hours = $parts[0][0] + $minutes_overflow;

    if($hours != 0)
        return $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
    else
        return $minutes.':'.$seconds;
}
```

Comment: this fails on videos that report a duration of 1:00:01. see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35836604

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution, test completed!

```
preg_match_all("/PT(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?/", $duration, $matches);

$hours   = strlen($matches[1][0]) == 0 ? 0 : substr($matches[1][0], 0, strlen($matches[1][0]) - 1);
$minutes = strlen($matches[2][0]) == 0 ? 0 : substr($matches[2][0], 0, strlen($matches[2][0]) - 1);
$seconds = strlen($matches[3][0]) == 0 ? 0 : substr($matches[3][0], 0, strlen($matches[3][0]) - 1);

return 3600 * $hours + 60 * $minutes + $seconds;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use two classes, 1 to call YouTube API, and one to convert the time. here it is simplified.

As you can see, YouTubeGet is a static class, but it does not have to be.  YouTubeDateInterval however has to be an instance due to the way that DateInterval works (which is being extended).

```
class YouTubeGet{
static public function get_duration($video_id, $api_key){
        // $youtube_api_key
        $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={$video_id}&part=contentDetails&key={$api_key}";
        // Get and convert. This example uses wordpress wp_remote_get()
        // this could be replaced by file_get_contents($url);
        $response = wp_remote_get($url);

        // if using file_get_contents(), then remove ['body']
        $result = json_decode($response['body'], true);
        // I've converted to an array, but this works fine as an object
        if(isset($result['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration'])){
            $duration = $result['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration'];
            return self::convtime($duration);
        }
        return false;
    }

    static protected function convtime($youtube_time){
        $time = new YouTubeDateInterval($youtube_time);        
        return $time->to_seconds();
    }   

}

class YouTubeDateInterval extends DateInterval {
    public function to_seconds() 
      { 
        return ($this->y * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
               ($this->m * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
               ($this->d * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
               ($this->h * 60 * 60) + 
               ($this->i * 60) + 
               $this->s; 
      } 
}
```

usage is either about passing a iso 8601 date to YouTubeDateInterval.

```
$time = new YouTubeDateInterval('PT2H34M25S');
$duration_in_seconds = $time->to_seconds();
```

or passing the YouTubeGet the api and video id key

```
$duration_in_seconds = YouTubeGet::get_duration('videoIdString','YouTubeApiKeyString');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code to get, convert and display the video duration

```
$vidkey = "           " ; // for example: cHPMH26sw2f
$apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" ;

$dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=$vidkey&key=$apikey");
$VidDuration =json_decode($dur, true);
foreach ($VidDuration['items'] as $vidTime) 
{
$VidDuration= $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration'];
}
// convert duration from ISO to M:S
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval($VidDuration));
echo $date->format('i:s') ;
```

Replace xxxxxxx with your API Key
Results: 13:07

Answer (score 1):

try this will give you duration by seconds

```
function video_length($youtube_time)
{
    $duration = new \DateInterval($youtube_time);
    return $duration->h  * 3600 + $duration->i  * 60  + $duration->s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$duration = new \DateInterval($data['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration']);
echo $duration->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDuration($duration): string
{
    preg_match_all("/P(\d+D)?T(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?/", $duration, $m);

    $days = empty($m[1][0]) ? 0 : substr($m[1][0], 0, -1);
    $hours = empty($m[2][0]) ? 0 : substr($m[2][0], 0, -1);
    $minutes = empty($m[3][0]) ? 0 : substr($m[3][0], 0, -1);
    $seconds = empty($m[4][0]) ? 0 : substr($m[4][0], 0, -1);

    $hours += ($days * 24);

    $hours = sprintf("%02d", $hours);
    $minutes = sprintf("%02d", $minutes);
    $seconds = sprintf("%02d", $seconds);

    return "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
}
```

example:

```
input: PT2H34M25S
output: 02:34:25

input: P1DT3H12M8S
output: 27:12:08
```

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this by using `use Carbon\CarbonInterval` library.

```
public static function convert_youtube_duration_to_normal(string $youtube_time)
{
    return CarbonInterval::create($youtube_time)->forHumans();
}


Functions::convert_youtube_duration_to_normal('PT4M25S')
```

Which returns as output `"4 minutes 25 seconds"`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following function:

```
function covtime($youtube_time) 
{
    $hours = '0';
    $minutes = '0';
    $seconds = '0';

    $hIndex = strpos($youtube_time, 'H');
    $mIndex = strpos($youtube_time, 'M');
    $sIndex = strpos($youtube_time, 'S');
    $length = strlen($youtube_time);
    if($hIndex > 0)
    {
        $hours = substr($youtube_time, 2, ($hIndex - 2));
    }
    if($mIndex > 0)
    {
        if($hIndex > 0)
        {
            $minutes = substr($youtube_time, ($hIndex + 1), ($mIndex - ($hIndex + 1)));
        }      
        else
        {
            $minutes = substr($youtube_time, 2, ($mIndex - 2));
        }
    }
    if($sIndex > 0)
    {
        if($mIndex > 0)
        {
            $seconds = substr($youtube_time, ($mIndex + 1), ($sIndex - ($mIndex + 1)));
        }
        else if($hIndex > 0)
        {
            $seconds = substr($youtube_time, ($hIndex + 1), ($sIndex - ($hIndex + 1)));
        }      
        else
        {
            $seconds = substr($youtube_time, 2, ($sIndex - 2));
        }
    }
    return $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this -

```html
function covtime($youtube_time){
    $start = new DateTime('@0'); // Unix epoch
    $start->add(new DateInterval($youtube_time));
    if (strlen($youtube_time)>8)
    {
    return $start->format('g:i:s');
}   else {
 return $start->format('i:s');
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

DateTime and DateInterval not working in Yii or some php version.
So this is my solution. Its work with me.

```
function convertTime($time){        
    if ($time > 0){
        $time_result = '';
        $hours = intval($time / 3600);
        if ($hours > 0)
            $time_result = $time_result.$hours.':';
        $time = $time % 3600;
        $minutes = intval($time / 60);
        $seconds = $time % 60;
        $time_result = $time_result.(($minutes > 9)?$minutes:'0'.$minutes).':';
        $time_result = $time_result.(($seconds > 9)?$seconds:'0'.$seconds);
    }else 
        $time_result = '0:00';        

    return $time_result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why the complication. Think outside the box.

```
    $seconds = substr(stristr($length, 'S', true), -2, 2);
    $seconds = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $seconds);
    $minutes =  substr(stristr($length, 'M', true), -2, 2);
    $minutes = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $minutes);
    $hours =  substr(stristr($length, 'H', true), -2, 2);
    $hours = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $hours);
```

OK. preg_replace is not really needed, but I put it to guarantee only numbers.

Then for my formatting (which you can do however you like without limits),

```
      if($hours == 0){ 
      $h= '';
      }else{ 
      $h= $hours.':';
      }

      if($minutes <10){ 
      $m= '0'.$minutes.':'; 
        if($h == ''){
        $m= $minutes.':'; 
        }
          if ($minutes == 0){
            $m= $minutes;                 
          }
      }else{ 
      $m= $minutes.':';
      }

      if($seconds <10){ 
      $s= '0'.$seconds; 
      }else{ 
      $s= $seconds;
      }
      $time= $h . $m . $s.'s';
```