# Convert youtube api returned time format to seconds using PHP

Tags: php, time, youtube-api

So the received duration/time format from api is this ;

```
PT1H1M6S
```

how can i convert this into seconds using any php function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Youtube Data API V3 video duration format to seconds in JavaScript/Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148885/converting-youtube-data-api-v3-video-duration-format-to-seconds-in-javascript-no)

Comment: Others are more [PHP specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393230/convert-youtube-api-v3-video-duration-in-php) but that is the better answer. Maybe makes sense to parse in JS anyway?  Not sure for your case.

Comment: @ficuscr , i tried that php solution but it gives in Hour minutes and seconds format . i am looking for only seconds format.

Comment: Sorry @Andreas moved it into an answer because I thought saying 'use division' might be too snarky :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the best solution I've encountered with Google on how to convert ISO 8601 values to seconds.

+1 for no preg function use. Right tool for the job in my opinion.

Code credit to RuudBurger - copied from gist: https://gist.github.com/w0rldart/9e10aedd1ee55fc4bc74

```
/**
 * Convert ISO 8601 values like P2DT15M33S
 * to a total value of seconds.
 *
 * @param string $ISO8601
 */
function ISO8601ToSeconds($ISO8601){
    $interval = new \DateInterval($ISO8601);

    return ($interval->d * 24 * 60 * 60) +
        ($interval->h * 60 * 60) +
        ($interval->i * 60) +
        $interval->s;
}

echo ISO8601ToSeconds('P20DT15M33S'); // Returns a value of 1728933
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Function to convert ISO8601 Duration To Seconds.

```
<?php

function convertISO8601DurationToSeconds($iso8601DurationStr)
{
   $interval = new \DateInterval($iso8601DurationStr);
   $seconds = $interval->h * 3600 + $interval->i * 60 + $interval->s;
   return (int) $seconds;
}

   echo convertISO8601DurationToSeconds('PT1H1M6S');

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

This can be done using the RegEx:
^PT(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S)?$
You can then use the various PHP methods for manipulating RegEx to store the time in variables.