# Convert a playtime format PT to M:SS

Tags: php, time

How can I convert a `PT4M4S` format like from YouTube API format to a viewable format like `4:04`
... and maybe for interest additional `PT1H4M4S` to `1:04:04` both with the beginning zero by the four.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert duration into seconds with function below ([extracted from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44573805/7540423)) :

   `function ISO8601ToSeconds($ISO8601) {`

   ```
       $interval = new \DateInterval($ISO8601);

       return 
       ($interval->d * 24 * 60 * 60) +
       ($interval->h * 60 * 60) +
       ($interval->i * 60) +
       ($interval->s);
   }
   ```
2. Format the time in seconds to fit your needs :

   `gmdate("H:i:s", ISO8601ToSeconds('PT4M4S'));`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

**Disclaimer:** This hasn't been tested so I don't know if it works

```
<?php 
    $str = 'PT1H4M4S'; 
    $str = substr($str, 2); //Returns 4M4S

    $timeArray = str_split($string, 2); //Returns { '4M', '4S' }

    $formattedTime = '';

    foreach ($timeArray as $time) {
        switch (substr($time, 0)) //Looking at first value
        {
            case 'H':
                $formattedTime .= substr($time, 1); //Returns 4
                break;
            case 'M':
                $formattedTime .= str_pad(substr($time, 1), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); //Returns 04
                break;
            case 'S':
                $formattedTime .= str_pad(substr($time, 1), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); //Returns 04
                break;
        }

        $formattedTime .= ':';
    }

    $formattedTime .= substr($time, -1); //Removes last ':'

    echo $formattedTime; 
?>
```