# Youtube data API version 3 pagination

Tags: api, youtube, pagination

I understand that youtube response contains the next and previous page tokens and we can use those to go to previous and next pages.

eg :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?&key={key}&part=snippet&maxResults=20&order=viewCount&q=abc&type=video&videoDuration=long&videoType=movie&pageToken=Cd323A
```

My question is how can I navigate to ***nth***   page of particular search?

Please note that some people may see this is impossible. But I have seen some site implemented this.

Answer (score 13):

Youtube API only provides `NextPageToken` and `PreviousPageToken`, that's it, sorry: see documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

You can still make a pagination item but you will have to implement it by calling multiple times the URL, passing the `NextPageToken` as `pageToken` in your requestion every time, and caching results.

By the way, this question is already answered here (see the 1st point of the answer): [youtube data api v3 php search pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253925/youtube-data-api-v3-php-search-pagination)

Quoting them:

> In particular your case where you need 50 pages per page and you are
>   showing 3 pagination like (1,2,NEXT) then you need to fetch results
>   two times. Both the results you will keep in cache so for page 1 and 2
>   results will be retrieved from cache. For next you make it sure that
>   you are making query google again by sending nextPageToken.
>
> Thus to show pagination 1-n and every page 50 results then you need to
>   make n-1 queries to google api. But if you are showing 10 results per
>   page then you cane make single query of 50 results using which you can
>   show first 5 pages (1-5) with the help of retrieved results and at
>   next you should again send next page token like above.
>
> NOTE- Google youtube api provide 50 results max.

Comment: I read the given link before I post the question and I still post this because the caching the result will lead same result even if the real situation changes in the youtube. This will lead to have same results set till the cache clear. I really appreciate your attempt.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your last point: what is wrong with the cache for you?

Comment: If the result is cached the users will see the same results. It is not the expected behavior. It is ideally should be dynamic results as YouTube (when the search weight and threshold values are changing the results should be changed)

Comment: No, we are talking about local caching, so the results will not be the same for all users. And you have to change your cache if your search change

Comment: Could you please tell me, how do you cache locally without affecting the long term result. If I plan to show pagination for the next 10 items how could I do that. I am awarding the bounty as a gratitude.

Comment: When you do your initial query, you just have to store the nextPageToken in an array for each page you need. Then if your search change, clean your array and start again to fill it

Comment: Where can I find this `NextPageToken` or `PreviousPageToken`?

Comment: In each reply provided by the API

Answer (score 3):

nextPageToken and prevPageToken comes with the api request.
[image: check the nextPageToken]

Now you save the token in an array and then insert it as a nextPageToken in another api call and you will get the next page. The same way you will get a prevPageToken when u get the next page results.

Hope it helps.

Comment: will nextPageToken survive until tomorrow, when I get more quota points, I want to get a few thousand videos from a channel?