# How to get result from youtube api search morethan 5?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried to get youtube search from this link

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key={my_api_key}&q=plane
```

it's work good. But i want to know how can i get result morethan 5 ?

ref : `https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list`

Comment: API v3 should provide a parameter which can set the amount of returning results. try to add `&max-results=150` at the end. 150 can be replaced by every number

Comment: still show 5 result `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key={my_api_key}&q=plane&max-results=150`

Comment: have you tried onlinetools like postman or something like that? Maybe it´s code issue?

Comment: could yuo please show me some example link ?

Comment: my fault `maxResults` need to be between 0 and 50. [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) you can test some requests directly on youtube/google

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079501/youtube-data-api-version-3-pagination

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone needs a solution for this.

You just need to add `&maxResults=50` (to get a maximum of 50 results of course) at the end of the link / API call.

The person who asked the question was using `&max-results...` and not `&maxResults...` which is why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to set here is maxResults. Now, if you're still getting 5, the problem maybe that there's really no other videos to list or your search filter is wrong.

The nextPageToken solution do not apply if you have maxResult set to 50 but are only getting 5. The problem could be your filter or the number of videos available.