# Paginating in youtube API V3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am new at youtube API V3 now I can get the videos of some user and display them at my site but now when the result is more than 50 video I want to make a paging for them lets say that my result is 240 so I have 5 pages now how I make the request for page number 4 with out go through links 1 , 2 or 3
Here is my list request:-

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUdxi8d8qRsRyUi2ERYjYb-w&key={myKey}
```

there are a page token that allow me to go through the links but that mean that I must to use next and prev requests 
so is there any way to load page 4 direct ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23439904/4241842) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to load a specific page directly you need to call the API with the `nextPageToken` for each page (so 4 times in your example).

Comment: but by this way the requests will be to large and it will finish my quota

Comment: You can specify `part` to be `id` in your requests for the pages where you just need the next page token and nothing else. This would reduce the quote cost for each call. Also, caching would reduce the cost but would need to be implemented specifically for your application.

Comment: There's also a way to reduce the number of fields returned (which may also reduce the quota impact and bandwidth usage), by adding the `fields` parameter and specifying which fields (and their subfields in parentheses) should be returned in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend this approach but include it for completleness as it provides a direct solution to the question whereas the other answer provides alternatives.

Youtube seems to use the same `pageToken`s regardless of playlist or date of access. E.g., the `pageToken` for the 2nd page is always `CDIQAA`, for the 3rd page `CGQQAA`, etc.

These aren't guranteed to always remain the same, but based on stackoverflow posts from as early as 2014, it hasn't changed in a long time, so it's a reasonable assumption.

So you could make the request for the first five pages as you normally do, then persist the page tokens (e.g. in a local cache). Then whenever you need e.g. the 240th item in the future, simply look up the 5th page token (which happens to be `CMgBEAA`) and access that page directly.

Here are the 1st 9 page tokens:

```
1 <blank>
2 CDIQAA 
3 CGQQAA
4 CJYBEAA
5 CMgBEAA
6 CPoBEAA
7 CKwCEAA
8 CN4CEAA
9 CJADEAA
```