# display all youtube channel videos in a webpage

Tags: jquery, web, youtube-api

so i am making a simple HTML5 site and i have a channel on youtube that i want to get all the videos from it and display them as a list or grid!

i just want to know how can i get all videos from a channel on youtube with Jquery or PHP

*i have been looking for a solution and yet found nothing
all i found was this site that makes it ready for you but when you click the video it will take you to their website http://ytchannelembed.com/create-your-free-youtube-widget/

Comment: Have a look at the [Youmax plugin](http://www.codehandling.com/2013/03/youmax-20-complete-youtube-channel-on.html).

Comment: Looks great! too bad it's 5AM and i can't test it yet

Comment: You can refer this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607356/displaying-youtube-videos-from-specific-channel/

Comment: You can implement your code by using below reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607356/displaying-youtube-videos-from-specific-channel/40778347?sfb=2#40778347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the Youmax plugin which is a jQuery solution as per your requirement. When you click the thumbnail, videos will be displayed either in a  popup or inside the widget itself. So there is no redirect and users will stay on your site. Below are the 2 versions -

Youmax 2.1 - Free version 
https://github.com/codehandling/youmax

Youmax 7.0 - Premium version 
http://codecanyon.net/item/youmax-youtube-channel-on-your-website/9989505

Let me know if you need any help implementing them :)

Comment: can i get updated jQuery solution as this link is not working now