# Youtube api v3 cannot retrieve all videos from a channel

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to use youtube data api to get all videos from a channel. But it didn't work for a particular channel. (It works for several other channels.)

As you can see from the screenshot, this channel has 135 videos.

[image]

However, I used playlistitems and search api, as below. They only return 9 videos. What is the problem here? Thanks.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUhTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg&key={YOUR_API_KEY} 

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UChTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg&maxResults=50&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: It seems channel.list returns the channelId=UChTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg. However, when I check a video that's not included using videos.list, the corresponding channelId=UC8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA. What a disaster...

Comment: Check this SO question [YouTube API v3 - List uploaded videos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930200/youtube-api-v3-list-uploaded-videos) if it can help you;)

Comment: You can refer my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607356/displaying-youtube-videos-from-specific-channel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're dealing with two different channels with the same `title` but this is acceptable because of the `customUrl`s are different, here the details:

## 1. `DharmaYogaCenter`: UChTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg - title: DharmaYogaCenter

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=UChTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

````
``` json 
{
    "title": "DharmaYogaCenter",
    "description": "We are a full yoga center located in Bremerton Washington.  We believe yoga and meditation is for everyone.  Stop by our Yoga Center and enjoy a blissful meditation, yoga class or just some good community.  We offer many free classes every month.  www.dharmayogacenter.net",
    "customUrl": "DharmaYogaCenter",
    "publishedAt": "2009-06-11T21:43:56.000Z",
    ...
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UChTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg",
    ...
    "videoCount": "9"
    ...
```
````

You can check there are only few videos in here: [uploaded videos in channel UC8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg/videos)

### "youtube#channel" `"id": UChTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg`

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UChTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
get the playlist id of channel's `"uploads": "UUhTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg"`

#### uploads playlist: `UUhTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg` "totalResults": 9

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUhTMiw43iw4w-ggOEXmPtfg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/yvjEzYc-CE8RBoXkFDTMPf_O1XM\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 9,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },...
```

## 2. `TheDharmaTube`: UC8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA - title: DharmaYogaCenter

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=UC8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

```
{ 
    "title": "DharmaYogaCenter",
    "description": "Be receptive",
    "customUrl": "TheDharmaTube",
    "publishedAt": "2011-02-24T22:54:31.000Z",
    ...
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UU8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA",
    ...
    "videoCount": "142"
```

You can check there are a lot more videos in here: [uploaded videos in channel UC8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA/videos) ..scroll down once opened to load all the videos

### "youtube#channel" `"id": UC8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA`

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UC8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
get the playlist id of channel's `"uploads": "UU8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA"`

#### uploads playlist: `UU8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA` "totalResults": 142

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UU8hnoz74NP5V5sxkuxXk2kA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
"totalResults": 142,

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/jm3DhRxnqdMzu1DGtIoiLbpEFY4\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 142,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },...
```