# What is difference of "Posted video" and "Uploads" in YouTube Channel? And how to get them through YouTube Data v3 API?

Tags: youtube-api

I am in the middle of developing a YouTube client using YouTube Data v3 API, and is playing with two different channels observed:

1. [Go Pro Channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/GoProCamera/videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/GoProCamera/videos)
2. [YouTube curated Sports Channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw/videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw/videos)

In Go Pro channel, I can also choose a video filter: "Uploads", "Liked" and "Posted Videos". I am much puzzled by the "Uploads" and "Posted Videos" filter, which from my observation, on this channel, they are giving the same result. But in YouTube curated sports channel, there is only "Posted Video" option there.

For the past hours, I can not find any definitive explanation from YouTube v2/v3's API documentation, and what is more bothering me is, I can not find any API to retrieve the video entry data in those channels.

For Go Pro Channel, I could at least rely on the method mentioned here to get uploaded video: [How do I get a list of uploaded videos for a certain channel with the new YouTube Data API (V3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504899/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-uploaded-videos-for-a-certain-channel-with-the-new-youtub)

But for curated channels, even this method does not work, the playlist given in channel query result is always empty:

```
Request


GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2CcontentDetails%2Csnippet&id=UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.dwCMU6xpf5N9AxwAAABgIM94lgv7jGHw0h0oEjs6uZUdPFO28CDYhbvgXdKTjw
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer


Response


200 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"WFPuK6TsnblcGPcnMex79s42ynQ/qpdedwjxXQ-COrk0dODO-8DTAx0\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"WFPuK6TsnblcGPcnMex79s42ynQ/TP96YXZ0G4VPdQ7fd2IYgW79rW0\"",
   "id": "UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Sports",
    "description": "Sport is all forms of usually competitive physical activity which, through casual or organised participation, aim to use, maintain or improve physical ability and skills while providing entertainment to participants, and in some cases, spectators. Hundreds of sports exist, from those requiring only two participants, through to those with hundreds of simultaneous participants, either in teams or competing as individuals. Sport is generally recognised as activities which are based in physical athleticism or physical dexterity, with the largest major competitions such as the Olympic Games admitting only sports meeting this definition, and other organisations such as the Council of Europe using definitions precluding activities without a physical element from classification as sports. However, a number of competitive, but non-physical, activities claim recognition as mind sports.\nThis channel was generated automatically by YouTube's video discovery system.",
    "publishedAt": "2013-12-15T20:39:04.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/i/Egdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw/1.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/i/Egdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw/mq1.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/i/Egdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw/hq1.jpg"
     }
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "likes": "LLEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw",
     "uploads": "UUEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

--

```
Request


GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2CcontentDetails%2Csnippet&playlistId=UUEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer


Response


200 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"WFPuK6TsnblcGPcnMex79s42ynQ/0ky7gu-r2KEON6-qkmzKhU77B-Q\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

It seems to me this is a dead end now, so is there any way to get videos from this kind of curated channels?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got the channel ID of the curated channel, you can just use the search endpoint to get the videos; for example, this API call will receive the 50 most recent videos added to YouTube's sports channel:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw&maxResults=50&order=date&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thanks, your sample API call did output some results, but at the moment, they are totally different than the official channel contents(https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw/videos?flow=list&live_view=500&view=54) Any idea on this behavior?

Comment: Update, after reading more carefully with the search result using the provided API call, it just dumped me with all the playlist items under this channel, not the videos I want. If I force it to list video entries, it gave me empty result again.