# I am trying to get videos from a specific channel and my apps get unresponsive

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

```
ChannelListResponse channelListResponse = youtube.channels().
         list("brandingSettings,localizations").setForUsername("jacksepticeye").execute();

        List<Channel> channelList = channelListResponse.getItems();
        Channel channel = channelList.get(0);
        ChannelContentDetails contentDetails = channel.getContentDetails();
        String uploads = contentDetails.getRelatedPlaylists().getUploads();


        List<PlaylistItem> playlistItemList = new ArrayList<PlaylistItem>();

        YouTube.PlaylistItems.List playlistItemRequest =
                youtube.playlistItems().list("id,contentDetails,snippet");
        playlistItemRequest.setPlaylistId(uploads);
        playlistItemRequest.setFields(
                "items(contentDetails/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt),nextPageToken,pageInfo");
        PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemResult = playlistItemRequest.execute();

        playlistItemList.addAll(playlistItemResult.getItems());

        Iterator<PlaylistItem> playlistEntries = playlistItemList.iterator();
        List<VideoItem> items = new ArrayList<VideoItem>();
        while (playlistEntries.hasNext()) {
            VideoItem item = new VideoItem();
            PlaylistItem playlistItem = playlistEntries.next();
            item.setTitle(playlistItem.getSnippet().getTitle());
            item.setDescription(playlistItem.getContentDetails().getVideoId());
            items.add(item);
        }
        return items;
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong?
I am trying to follow the steps in this question [How do I get a list of uploaded videos for a certain channel with the new YouTube Data API (V3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504899/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-uploaded-videos-for-a-certain-channel-with-the-new-youtub)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the response and/or error codes/messages you've received?

Comment: @matthewayne I actually solved the problem. I wasn't setting the key :)

Comment: @LazyDev, if you have solved it, please share the answer as nobody has answered this question yet. :)